# Kendo Master Detail Grid With Checkbox Selection In Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

How do I bind kendo master detail grid with checkbox selection?

Here are the following kendo grid features link:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/advanced-features/hierarchy/

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/selection/

Comment: Can you please provide piece of code you have tried so far?

Comment: Do you want checkbox on the master, the detail, or both?